# Run regression in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Please see the fake data set.

```
library(data.table)
library(MASS)
n=5000
DT = data.table(
      grp=1:n,
      name=as.character(as.hexmode(1:n)), 
      x= sample(c(1:400),n,replace = TRUE)
    )

setkey(DT,grp)

UIDlist <- unique(DT[,grp])
IDnamelist <- paste0("V", 1 : length(UIDlist), sep = "")
test <- DT[, (IDnamelist):=lapply(UIDlist,function(x) grp ==x)][, V5000:= NULL]
```

I have a data.table, in which there're 4 columns, "grp", "Name", "x", "y". And then I add dummy on each level in "grp".
Then I need to run the regression using glm.nb in MASS package.

First I tried this

```
SumResult <- glm.nb(x ~ factor(uid), data = test)
```

But when adding dummies, we must notice that when there're N levels in "grp", we add N-1 dummies. So this method is not appropriate as far as I think.

So I tried this:

```
SumResult <- glm.nb( x ~ V1 + V2 + V3 + V4 + .....+ V4999  , data = test)
```

It's stupid to write all of the V1, V2, ... V4999 to do the regression.

Is there code can achieve the purpose?

Thanks

Comment: What's the purpose of `test`? PS: You can shortform your formula by using `x ~ .` and subsetting DT. Saves time on writing them all out!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking. But, regarding your comment that only `N-1` dummies gets added when the factor has `N` levels, this is as intended. If you have an intercept in the model (as you do) and add dummies for all `N` levels, you will have perfect collinearity; i.e., you model won't estimate.

Comment: @Jason thanks for your workaround. I edited the problem. Aside from the collinearity problem, I first want to achieve the how to add "v1 + v2 + v3 + v4....+ v4999" wisely. Could you provide some insights?

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen Thanks for work around, now I edited the problem. Do you have ideas?

Comment: @Bigchao I'm still not clear on what you want, but writing `x ~ .` is the same as writing `x ~ V1 + V2 + ... VN`. If you want to exclude the last variable you just subset your data `test[-ncol(test)]`. So you would have something like `glm.nb(x ~ .,data=test[-ncol(test])`. (Or whatever subset you need). The "." in the formula literally means "everything else".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to create your formula object by string manipulation

```
formula <- as.formula(paste0("x ~ ", paste(names(test)[-(1:3)], collapse = " + ")))
sumresult <- glm.nb(formula, data = test)
```

You can also use the more readable code of @BrandonBertelsen

```
glm.nb(x ~ ., data = test[-c(1:3)])
```

Comment: Achieved in a more straighforward fashion with `glm.nb(x~.,data=test[-c(1:3)])`

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen Thanks, you are right. I think I'll remove this answer since you already replied in the comment.

Comment: Just update your answer.. it's still not really clear if this solves the problem given the description.