# Look up values between columns in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with more than 3000 columns, most of which are dummy variables ( "TRUE" or "FALSE").

For given observation, I want to find the columns names of which value is "TRUE"

Can I do this in data.table?

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(ID = c(1:2), V1 = c(TRUE,FALSE), V2 = c(FALSE, TRUE), V3 = c(FALSE, TRUE))
```

And this is what I want.

```
   ID  TRUE    
1:  1   V1
2:  2   V2&V3
```

But I tried to use `lapply` `.SD` But failed.

To simplify this issue, I think it's simple to run a query based on single observation.
Say, if I run the query based on observation 1, here's what I want.

```
   ID   V1    
1:  1   TRUE
```

Similarly, if I run the query based on observation 2.

```
   ID   V2     V3
1:  1   TRUE   TRUE
```

I know how to subset based on column's value.

```
subsetted <- DT[ which(DT$V1=='T'), ]
```

But based on rows, How to do it? Thanks!

Comment: 3000 columns is pretty "wide" for a data.table. The package works best with "long" data.tables. Are you sure that you could not restructure your data?

Comment: Hey, Roland, Thanks for walking around. most of the 3000 columns are dummy variables. I added dummies on each ID for the following regression purpose. There're 3000 different IDs, so the the data.table got wide. Technically, could you offer some ideas about how to figure it out? Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of your exercise. If you have a decent sized data.table the column you want to create will be useless. And whatever you are trying to achieve with this, you should do it prior to dummy encoding.

Comment: @Roland Thanks for your comments. My supervisor told me to run binomial regression with the dummies on each ID. What's the purpose..Honestly speaking, I disagreed with him, but I need to fulfill the task...

Comment: `glm` doesn't require to do the dummy encoding manually. Almost all regression functions in R do dummy encoding automatically for factor variables.

Comment: @Roland yeah, but I'm not sure whether the `factor` code is what I want. I also asked one question regarding to what you mentioned, and describes my puzzle about `glm`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364256/run-regression-in-data-table Comments are extremely welcome!

Comment: Yes, you want `factor` variables and let `glm` do the dummy encoding for you. If you don't understand how that works, you should do some studying. It has been explained several time here and on stats.stackexchange.com. I also doubt a bit if you should be using data.table. It adds a layer of complexity that you only need if you have a large dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `melt` in the package `reshape2` to convert the data into a "long" format whilst filtering for `TRUE` and then concatenated by ID in the final step.

```
DT <- data.table(ID = c(1:2), V1 = c(TRUE,FALSE), V2 = c(FALSE, TRUE), V3 = c(FALSE, TRUE))

library(reshape2)
DT2 = data.table(melt(DT, id.vars="ID"))[value ==TRUE]
```

This gives the data in the following format:

```
   ID variable value
1:  1       V1  TRUE
2:  2       V2  TRUE
3:  2       V3  TRUE
```

Then concatenate the variables by ID.

```
DT2[,list(variables=paste(variable, collapse =" ")),by=ID]

   ID variables
1:  1        V1
2:  2     V2 V3
```

If you prefer to see the variables separated by ampersand then use `collapse = "&"`.

But I will reiterate what Roland said in the comments, a table like this with all sorts of combinations of V1&V8&V100 etc. does not lend itself to statistical analysis or reporting at all.  There is something intuitively not logical in what you are trying to do here so I suggest you think what analyses you wish to undertake and then set about coding variables & structuring data accordingly.